# How to lose focus when moving outside a text box (on iPad, using ionic 1)?

Tags: html, forms, ionic-framework, ipad

**Current behavior:**
If my cursor is in a text box (as seen on the screenshot below), and that I click on one of the radio buttons located under the text box, my screen jumps back to the text box.

The issue started back in March 2023 or so. We are experiencing the issue for iPads.

We are using a very old framework that is not supported anymore unfortunately (Ionic 1), if anyone has an idea on what I could do to make sure that clicking on the radio button doesn't make me jump back to the text box, would be great. If I click anywhere other than in the text box, before clicking on the radio button, I don't have the issue, but it is not intuitive for users.
[image: Text box and radio buttons]

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```js
  // Suppose the text box's ID is "textarea"
  const textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');

  const isOut = () => {
    const boundary = textarea.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (boundary.bottom < 0) {
      textarea.blur();
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', isOut, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript code for the radio button:

```
  selectSort() {
  this.onSortSelect();
  this.blurInput();
} ...

blurInput() {
  const inputElement = document.activeElement;
  if (inputElement) {
    inputElement.blur();
  }
}...
```

In the `selectSort()` function, we added a call to `this.blurInput()`, which will trigger the `blurInput()` function. This function retrieves the currently focused element using `document.activeElement` and then calls the `blur()` method on it to remove the focus.

By adding these changes, clicking on a radio button will now cause the cursor to lose focus.

Thanks!